# How to consume button click inside <a> tag to prevent link being followed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've added a button *inside* a link tag, with a little cross image, that I will eventually use to actually remove that element without it following the link also:

```js
function detectClick(message) {
  window.alert("Detected: " + message);
}
```

```html
<div><a style="border: solid 1px black; vertical-align: middle; display:inline-block;" href="http://www.google.com"><button style="position: relative; float: right;" onclick="detectClick('Google')"><img src="cross.png"></button>Google</a></div>
```

How do I consume that click, once it has executed *detectClick(...)*, in order to prevent navigation away from the current page?

**NOTE:** Ideally, without using jQuery.

Comment: `return false` ?

Comment: Then take the link out all together and just have the button.

Comment: Patrick, the link still has to be clickable unless you click the cross button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First change your function to:

```
function detectClick(message){
    window.alert("Detected: " + message);
    return false; // add this line
}
```

then change the `onclick` handler to:

```
onclick="return detectClick('Google')" // note the "return"
```

Please do note that AFAIK the HTML standard does not allow to have a button inside an anchor.

Comment: Thanks Matteo. With regards to the HTML standard compliance bit, not to worry - this is not for production code, it's just some in-house dev admin. Your solution worked great.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function detectClick(message){
  window.alert("Detected: " + message);
  return false;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `return false;` at the end of `detectClick` and you need to return detectClick on your onclick event.

**Explanation**: The `return` value of the event handler tells the browser whether the default browser action should occur. Since `click`ing on your button by default triggers the `click` event of its parent, the link, `return false;` will prevent that default from happening, which is your exact intention.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your href tag from link tag. Add a id to that link tag. And assign the href value in the detectClict(). like-->

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Consume Click Test</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <div><a id = "link" style="border: solid 1px black; vertical-align:middle; display:inline-block;" > <button style="position: relative; float: right;" onclick="detectClick('Google')"><img src="cross.png"></button>Google</a>     </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function detectClick(message){
        window.alert("Detected: " + message);
        document.getElementById("link").href = "http://www.google.com";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Consume Click Test</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <div><a style="border: solid 1px black; vertical-align: middle; display:inline-block;" href="javascript:void 0;"><button style="position: relative; float: right;" onclick="detectClick('Google')"><img src="cross.png"></button>Google</a></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function detectClick(message){
        window.alert("Detected: " + message);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Using `javascript: void(0)` in href is not what the OP wants. He wants the link not be followed so href should be a valid url.