# Prevent Parent Click(a) Event When Child Element(input) is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `a` tag which wraps and have some content inside. When the box clicked it redirect to some other page. At the same time I have `input type="button"` element inside the `a` wrapper. And this `button` has to redirect to a separate page when clicked.

So far I have tried some jquery methods and all of them lead me to the failure.

I formed a sample structure here.

```js
$(".wrapper").click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.className == "btn") {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).find(".btn").attr('data-link');
    console.log(link);
    //window.location.href = link;
  }
});
```

```css
a.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}

a.wrapper * {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="google.com" class="wrapper">
  <span>some content</span>
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="click me" data-link="yahoo.com" />
</a>
```

How can I prevent the `a` tag click when I click the `button`?

Comment: Your `preventDefault` already accomplishes that, right?

Comment: It doesn't sir, when I click the `btn` console says the value in `data-link`, but the page get directed to the `a href` value

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621918/how-to-consume-button-click-inside-a-tag-to-prevent-link-being-followed

Comment: I could not find any problem. When i clicked on anchor tag, it's redirecting to google.com and when  I clicked on button, its redirecting to yahoo.com.....I could not identify the what you are facing.

Comment: @kish Now that worked for me sir. Thank you

Comment: `input[type="button"]` has no default action. So there's no point in using `preventDefault()`

Comment: @JitendraRangpariya I don't understand what is the problem here. I solved this with the reference of question that `kish` marked out in the comment section. But still I would like to know one thing that is this problem occurred because of any css lines? Because I didn't my css lines to the question? Are there any possibilities?

Comment: @Elish `preventDefault` is for `a` tag's event

Comment: Oh my bad, i misread your code @Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your goal?
an a is a text link while a button is a HTML element and both send ya somewhere. Why in the world would ya mix them together?
If you are thinking you need to for the .wrapper then you need to understand that CSS is often time better bigger and more specialized.
A class for btn is so generic that many web developers style an entire brand with it then add flavor for each with id's
If this is truly a special button try using an #id with the css.

```
<form>
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="wrapper"><span>some content</span></a>
<button type="submit" class="btn" id="special_button" formaction="https://www.yahoo.com" >
</form>
```

CSS add

```
#special_button {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari add all the browsers your targeting */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

#special_button:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: You answer is not clear enough, and I would like to where is the `js` code to redirect page when the `button` is clicked?

Comment: Gotcha, fixed:)

Comment: This is a nice suggestion sir. But I can't change the html dom since this a modification asked by the client. If I change the dom I will need to change lots of css and js rules. Between thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Understood what framework is using html Dom that old so I can stay away from those jobs:)